# Does InfluxDB provide a Java API?

Tags: java, database, api, influxdb, dolphindb

I can run DolphinDB scripts with DolphinDB Java API just like this:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import com.xxdb.DBConnection;
import com.xxdb.data.Vector;

public class HelloDolphinDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
      try{ 
          DBConnection conn=new DBConnection();
          boolean success=conn.connect("localhost",1220,"admin","123456");  
          System.out.println(success);
          String script="n=10\n" + 
                "x=rand(10, n)\n" + 
                "y=rand(10, n)*2\n" + 
                "add(x,y) ";
          Vector result = (Vector)conn.run(script);
          System.out.println(result.getString());              
       }
       catch(Exception e){}
   }
}
```

and get the result:

```java
true
[14,2,21,14,5,12,0,3,17,16]
```

wondering if InfluxDB provides a Java API for a quick connection to InfluxDB and run scripts easily.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.influxdb/influxdb-java

Comment: Please, try to search "InfluxDB java client", I am sure you will find a lot of good material on this topic :) https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java (1), https://www.baeldung.com/java-influxdb (2)

Answer (score 1):

Check the official documentation [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/api_client_libraries/) for all programming languages and specifically for java check [this](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/api_client_libraries/) out. Please note that these are community provided libraries for different programming languages so the version of InfluxDB supported is also worth considering.
AFAIK InfluxDB exposes a http API for interacting with it and these all libraries are wrapper over that.

Answer (score 0):

For influx db 1.x you can use: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java

For influx db 2.x use https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-java